# Why is complex numbers considered numbers while vectors quantities?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, terminology

A vector is said to be a quantity because it has both magnitude and direction.  A matrix is also said to be a quantity.  So it seems it is custom to call a combination of numbers a quantity.  Then why is a complex number, also a combination of two numbers (one for the real part, one for the imaginary part), called a number, not a quantity?

Comment: I think you're reading way too much into these terms. They aren't formally defined anywhere (except vector, but direction and magnitude are not part of that definition, so in this particular case I think we can consider it not formally defined).

Comment: Basically [historical reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#History) but also due to the fact that they share with other "numbers" basic features: addition, subtraction and multiplication of complex numbers can be naturally defined.

Comment: But your comment is right; for [J-R Argand (1806), they were "quantités imaginaires"](http://www.bibnum.education.fr/mathematiques/geometrie/essai-sur-une-maniere-de-representer-des-quantites-imaginaires-dans-les-cons)

Comment: "number" is not a mathematical concept. When calling something a number, it is done informally. The terms that are mathematical concepts that involve the word "number" are compound nouns, like "natural number", rational number", "complex number". There the word "number" is not playing the role of adding qualification that is a mathematical definition that distinguishes them from concepts that don't use that word.

Comment: Basically because you can multiply complex numbers.

Comment: Numbers (including real numbers) are an example of vectors, they form vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More formally, a *vector* is a member of a *vector space*, a set $V$ with the associated operations of *addition* and *scalar multiplication* satisfying [certain axioms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html).  It can easily be shown that $\mathbb{C}$ meets all of the vector space axioms.  Thus, complex numbers *are* vectors.  This is most obvious when plotting them on a Cartesian plane.

But $\mathbb{C}$ provides additional operations beyond the two required for general vectors.  In particular, you're not limited to multiplying complex numbers by real “scalars”; you can also multiply them *by other complex numbers*, using the definition $(a+ib)(c+id) = (ac - bd) + i(ad + bc)$.  From this, we can define a *multiplicative inverse* $\frac{1}{a+ib} = \frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}$ of any $a + ib \ne 0$.  Complex multiplication is associative, commutative, and distributive, thus satisfying [the field axioms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html).  This gives $\mathbb{C}$ a commonality with $\mathbb{R}$ (the real numbers) and $\mathbb{Q}$ (the rational numbers), which are also fields, and clearly established as being “numbers”.

Comment: Thanks, this also explains the similarity and difference between vectors and complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a precise mathematical definition or reason - it's more a question of English language than mathematics. But usage suggests we commonly use the word "number" when traditional numbers are *included* in whatever new type of entity we are talking about. We start with the Natural counting numbers, but when we extend them to positive/negative Integers, the Natural numbers are included. Likewise when we extend them to the Rationals (which are also *a combination of two numbers* in their usual representation as a fraction $a/b$), the integers are included, the Rationals are included in the Reals, and the Reals are included in the Complex numbers.

In the normal way of looking at things, vectors and matrices don't actually include the Real numbers as a subset of themselves. They are of different *types*, with incompatible operations. (Although 1D vectors and $1\times 1$ matrices look similar, they can't normally be mixed in the the same way as numbers. You can multiply an $n\times n$ matrix by a Real number but not by a $1\times 1$ matrix.) So we need another word for them.

But the distinction isn't very precise, and depends on context. Back in the late 1800s mathematicians like Grassman, Hamilton, and Clifford tried to extend the concept of numbers to cover *geometric* concepts in the various "hypercomplex" algebras, and a Clifford algebra in particular includes Reals (as scalars), vectors, Complex numbers, Quaternions, and more, all on an equal footing. In such a context, vectors are indeed considered to be "numbers". So it depends.

Comment: "You can multiply an n×n matrix by a Real number but not by a 1×1 matrix." - hmm... https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270171/651